# Is iter(subprocess.Popen_instance.stdout.readline, '') a busy loop?

Tags: python, subprocess

Lets consider following code construct:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)
```

Is this `for` loop a busy loop, or will it wait for output data from process lazily? How can I check this? Regardless of answer, is it part of language specification or implementation detail of CPython?

I'm interested in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x, on major OSes (Windows, macOS, Linux) and their respective kernels.

Comment: Even if `readline` were to return an empty string when no output is available, the loop would end instead of busywaiting.

Answer (score 2):

Since `readline` blocks, the loop is only as busy as there is output available to read.

Test from command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
args = ('cat', '-')
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))


$ ./x.py
a
a
b
b
<Ctrl-D>
```